# Can I use FaceTime video with an MacBook and email address only?

Tags: macbook-pro, facetime

I have a MacBook and set up FaceTime with an Apple ID, email only.

I can call from the MacBook FaceTime to another iPhone FaceTime user.

However, the iPhone FaceTime cannot make call the to MacBook's FaceTime, as the video icon is dimmed.

Is email-only FaceTime a/c not good for receiving video calls?

Comment: should work! Make sure FaceTime is enabled for your email address in FaceTime app -> Preferences.

Comment: The email on Mac's Facetime is enabled. However, when I add the email as a new contact into my iPhone, the new contact in iPhone does not have the video option (the "video" button is disabled).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your email account in your Macbook's FaceTime app and then get it verified from the verification email that you will receive.

Comment: Added, verified.